# Wordpress - Mysql: Need to extract values from a table filtering it on the field "course_id" from a second table

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've two tables
The first contains a list of member levels and associated courses (ex: course1 assigned to level1, course2 assigned to level1, course3 assigned to level2)
The second contains the list of all courses. I want to list only the courses associated to the current user level.
So I wrote:

global

```
 $wpcwdb, $wpdb;
    if (!current_user_can('administrator')) {
        function get_user_roles_by_user_id( $user_id ) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
        return empty( $user ) ? array() : $user->roles;
        }
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_ad_roles= get_user_roles_by_user_id($user_id);
        $user_ad_roles= implode("','",$user_ad_roles);
        echo $user_ad_roles;

// and this show the role (level) for the current user
// then interrogate the table 1

$SQL = "
                SELECT course_id 
                FROM $wpcwdb->map_member_levels
                WHERE member_level_id = '$user_ad_roles' ";
                $corsi_del_livello = $wpdb->get_results($SQL);

//now I need to filter the second table on the results of this first query

$SQL = "
                SELECT * 
                FROM $wpcwdb->courses
                WHERE course_id IN(".implode(',',$corsi_del_livello).")
                ORDER BY $orderBy $ordering";

        $courses = $wpdb->get_results($SQL);
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

In Wordpress I get the following error `"Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\profad.it\wp-content\plugins\wp-courseware\pages\page_course_das‌​hboard.inc.php on line 79"`. Line 79 is in the second query the "WHERE" clause.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Do you have an error log or can describe the current behaviour in more detail?

Comment: In wordpress I get the following error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\profad.it\wp-content\plugins\wp-courseware\pages\page_course_dashboard.inc.php on line 79"
Line 79 is in the second query the "WHERE" clause.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!
I made a Join among the two tables and that's the code:

```
global $wpcwdb, $wpdb;
    if (!current_user_can('administrator')) {
        function get_user_roles_by_user_id( $user_id ) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
        return empty( $user ) ? array() : $user->roles;
        }
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_ad_roles= get_user_roles_by_user_id($user_id);
        $user_ad_roles= implode("','",$user_ad_roles);
        echo $user_ad_roles;
    $livelli= $wpcwdb->map_member_levels;
        $corsi= $wpcwdb->courses;
        $SQL = "
                SELECT $livelli.course_id, $corsi.*
                FROM $corsi INNER JOIN $livelli ON $corsi.course_id = $livelli.course_id 
                WHERE $livelli.member_level_id = '$user_ad_roles' ";

        $courses = $wpdb->get_results($SQL);
    }
```